# Flutter "periodic" method is not defined

Tags: flutter

It says "periodic method is not defined" when I try to use the "Timer.periodic" method. Here is that part of the code and image of error message I get:

```
import 'dart:async';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int timeLeft = 5;

  void _startCountDown() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        timeLeft--;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zW2Cc.png)

I write accordingly to the document but I get the error anyway. How can I use this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error because you have a class named `Timer` in your code, or from one of your imports (other than `dart:async`). You can fix it by renaming your own `Timer` class to something else, or using the `hide` keyword from the import that has the `Timer` class.

For example, if you have an import from a package `abc` that has the `Timer` class, you can hide it this way:

```dart
import 'package:abc/abc.dart' hide Timer;
```

In VSCode, you can Ctrl+click on `Timer` to determine where that `Timer` class came from.

---

Alternatively, you can prefix your `dart:async` import:

```dart
import 'dart:async' as da;
```

And now you can use `Timer` like this:

```dart
da.Timer.periodic(...)
```

Comment: Oh, how did I not notice? Thank you for your answer:)